# Negação repetida necessita de vírgula?

Tags: vírgula, advérbios

Quando escrevo duas negações, devo separá-las por vírgula?

Exemplos:

1. Não vou não.
2. Não vou, não.

Qual é a correta?

Comment: Não acho que isso seja dupla negação. Dupla negação seria "não venho nenhum", "não há nada", etc - ver por exemplo [este artigo da CiberDúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-dupla-negacao-no-portugues-e-nas-demais-linguas-romanicas/19355). Mas a pergunta é boa! :)

Comment: Ele vai, sim. Nos vamos, sim. Também não são frases "duplas" declarativas. Essas frases são **faladas** e sempre há uma pausa no final antes do segundo não.  Então, eu voto por a vírgula. O segundo não é **enfático**.

Answer (score 4):

Talvez surpreendentemente, a primeira opção, sem vírgula, também está correta.

Se se tratasse de repetição, como em "Não, não vou.", em que o primeiro "não" responde a uma pergunta, e o restante da frase detalha a resposta, haveria vírgula, como colocado na [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8679/2764) de Rye.

Mas aqui o segundo "não" tem função intensivadora, de ênfase, ou seja:

> Não vou não.

é equivalente, embora menos enfático, a

> Não vou de jeito nenhum.

Exatamente essa expressão se encontra dicionarizada, sem vírgula, no [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/n%C3%A3o):

> adv.
> **5.** Repetido, reforça a negação: *Não vou não.*

A frase com vírgula ("Não vou, não.", "Não vou, de jeito nenhum.", etc.) também está correta mas, novamente, com significado diferente, de mera repetição ou detalhando a primeira parte (i.e., poderia ser "Não vou, a não ser que você me pague.", "Não vou, pelo menos não é minha intenção no momento.", etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A mais correta seria a *2.*, para isolar o advérbio de negação **"não"** na frase, pelos motivos mencionados [aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/virgula/) (suprimi partes que não interessavam):

> **Como usar a vírgula para separar elementos dentro de uma oração?**
>
> [...]
>
> *Elementos com diferentes funções sintáticas:*
>
> A vírgula separa elementos com função sintática diferente, isolando-os e realçando-os:
> [...]
>
> *Isola os advérbios sim e não, quando iniciam uma oração dando uma resposta, se referindo à oração anterior:*
>
> - Sim, vocês podem contar com nossa ajuda.
> - Não, não será possível concluir essa tarefa atempadamente.
>
> Isola elementos repetidos:
>
> - Estou com muita, muita, muita fome!
> - A vitória será minha, minha, minha!

Neste caso em particular, a vírgula deve ser utilizada para isolar o advérbio "não" porque, para além de surgir repetido, de modo a enfatizar algo que já foi dito, pode-se interpretar que se está a oferecer uma resposta a uma oração anterior (note que se poderia dizer, igualmente: "Não, não vou." sem perda de significado).

PS: Tudo isto não impede que, quando a frase é falada, isso seja feito sem a pausa imposta pela vírgula (como já foi amplamente discutido nos comentários, no discurso espontâneo, muitas vezes, as pausas/regras de pontuação são ignoradas). Mas, o mais correto, dado as regras gramaticais aqui descritas, é colocar a vírgula.

Comment: Rye, pelo menos no Brasil, penso que "não, não vou" ou "não vou, não" sejam diferentes de "não vou não". Esta não necessariamente responde a uma pergunta e é falada geralmente sem pausa; ex.: eu vejo alguém com uma arma e penso "não gosto disso não".

Comment: Pela gramática do Cunha e Cintra, essa separação do sim e não é dada como adjunto adverbial antecipado, não havendo um caso específico. Essa segunda de elemento repetido não é aplicável nesse exemplo. Eu pensaria que o correto seria não vou não porque essa é a ordem normal. Advérbio do lado do verbo, não haveria necessidade de vírgula. Se colocasse como "Não vou, não" eu pensaria que é o caso de uma separação de orações com a segunda com o verbo implícito "Não vou, não vou".

Comment: É, também eu acho que os casos expostos não se aplicam: o primeiro porque o "não" na pergunta não está no início da frase ("não, não vou"); o segundo porque o "não" não está repetido ("com muita, muita, muita fome", "será minha, minha, minha!", e talvez "com certeza que não, não, não vou"?) [Guarde-se espaço para diferenças transatlânticas.]

Comment: @Schilive Sim, mesmo em Portugal, a frase é dita quase sem pausa, mas isso não quer dizer que, em formato escrito, a pausa não exista e seja representada por uma vírgula (neste caso "Não vou, não"). Uma das coisas que distingue o enunciados orais de escritos é precisamente o facto de o locutor não seguir com tanto rigor as regras de correção gramatical, por isso é natural que quando a frase é falada, seja de forma mais rápida, sem respeito pela pontuação

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Os exemplos não são, de facto, os melhores - copiei-os diretamente do website que mencionei pois é a fonte que explica melhor os motivos para o uso da vírgula numa situação destas. Mas em enunciados escritos também sempre vi a frase com vírgula (Não vou, não) - servindo como forma de isolar e enfatizar o segundo advérbio que surge repetido. Pode ser verdade que a frase "Não vou não" também esteja correta, mas parece-me menos comum num enunciado escrito.

Comment: @Rye, sabes que a regra de "palavras seguidas" não é sem exceção? Podes, por exemplo, escrever "ele é bonito bonito" para dizer "ele é muito bonito". Como minha opinião, acho inútil uma vírgula, já que "não" é apenas uma reafirmação, assim como "inteligentemente terminou a prova inteligentemente". Se o significado não importar para as vírgulas, já tenho certeza, porque vírgula em advérbio no final de frase é opcional.

Comment: @Schilive "Ele é bonito bonito" deve levar vírgula (aliás, basta escrever a frase no Word para o programa se queixar) e o outro exemplo que deste não tem sentido. Quanto ao resto: claro que nem todas as regras de pontuação (em particular, no que toca ao uso de vírgula) são "escritas em pedra", mas isso não quer dizer que uma opção não seja (tecnicamente) mais correta do que a outra

Comment: Mais: neste caso, o que está em causa não é só o facto de o advérbio surgir duas vezes, mas também de exercer a mesma função em ambas as ocorrências. Com a repetição, estamos a enfatizar uma resposta que já foi dada com o primeiro "não" - daí eu considerar mais correto (keyword: mais) colocar a vírgula do que não a colocar

Comment: Fala e escritura são bem diferente.

Comment: @Rye, cito Bechara: «Na modalidade espontânea, mesmo
em literatura, pode-se obter a manifestação afetiva do superlativo mediante a repetição do
adjetivo: Ela é linda linda. Ou do advérbio: Ela é muito muito linda.». Creio que quando a repetição seja de mais de dois, já deva haver vírgula: «ela é muito, muito, muito linda».

Comment: @Schilive Sim, isso foi exatamente o que eu disse nos comentários mais acima ("Uma das coisas que distingue enunciados orais de escritos é precisamente o facto de o locutor não seguir com tanto rigor as regras de correção gramatical, por isso é natural que quando a frase é falada, seja de forma mais rápida, sem respeito pela pontuação"). Na modalidade oral/espontânea, não existe essa vírgula de que falo. Por isso mesmo também editei a resposta para tornar mais claro que me estava a referir apenas a enunciados escritos

Comment: Disculpa mas essa frase só pode ser falada. Não faz parte de um uso escrito.

Comment: A única pessoa a quem cabe avaliar isso é o OP.